# Updating angular material version is breaking my application

Tags: angular

I am trying to make my angular grid column headers as sticky by using the code -

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns ; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
```

But on research i found out that ***sticky:true*** is supported on Angular Material versions > 6.4.7 . My current version of Angular Material is 5.2.1 . When i tried updating my Angular material version and Angular cdk version to 6.4.7 it started giving me errors such as -

[image]

I tried updating my Angular/core version also , but it again broke some dependencies in Angular Node Modules .

Can anyone please help how can i resolve this and start using updated version without breaking ?

Comment: Please note that Angular 6 is not maintained anymore. You should upgrade at least to version 8, which is currently in LTS. See https://angular.io/guide/releases

Answer (score 2):

It's better to update your angular to the latest version `^10.0.0` and then install angular material. But it's not recommended here if you have some big projects. So, if you want a specific version of angular you can install it again. So reinstall & install your angular & material.

Using following commands to uninstall :

```sh
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
```

Using following command to re-install latest version:

```sh
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

**Or** use following command for specific version

```sh
npm install -g @angular/cli@wished.version.here
```

**e.g**

```sh
npm install -g @angular/cli@6.4.7
```

Then install angular material in your project using the following command:

```sh
npm install @angular/material@wished.version.here
```

**e.g**

```sh
npm install @angular/material@6.4.7
```

Try always install `@angular/material` with CLI and if you installed the latest version of Angular you can easily install the latest version of material as follows:

```sh
ng add @angular/material
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion , i will try and let u know